# Orthogonal projection

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sp.spectral-theory

Let $G$ be an operator with compact resolvent on a Hilbert space $H$ such that
$\ker G \neq \{0\}$.
Further let $P$ be the orthogonal projection onto $\ker G$, and let $G_{0} := G+P$.

My question is: are these conditions sufficient to say that $0\in\rho(G_{0})$? If the answer is negative, does the additional condition that $G$ is normal guarantee that $0\in\rho(G_{0})$?

Answer (score 2):

First question: no: consider e.g. $G:=\left[\begin{matrix} 0 & 1 \\0 & 0  \end{matrix}\right]$ and $G_0:=\left[\begin{matrix} 1 & 1 \\0 & 0  \end{matrix}\right]$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Second question: a normal operator $G$ is unitarily equivalent to a multiplication operator by a measurable function $f$ on some $L^2$ space;  $G_0$ is then the multiplication operator corresponding to the function $f+\chi_{\{f=0\}}$. So $G_0$ is invertible (meaning "linear homeomorphism") if and only if $\sigma(G)$ is bounded and  $0$ is isolated in it.

*edit*: As pointed out by Christian Rempling, the requirement  was just $0\in\rho(G_0)$, that is, $G_0$ injective and  $G_0^{-1}\in B(H)$, which is translated in $0$ being isolated in $\sigma(G)$. This is true if  for some $\lambda_0$.$(\lambda_0-G)^{-1}$ is a compact operator (for then $\sigma(G)$ is a discrete unbounded set).

Comment: The last statement is misleading: $0$ is automatically isolated in the spectrum because $G$ was assumed to have compact resolvent; $\sigma(G)$ will not be bounded, but we don't need this either.

Comment: In other words, the answer to the second question is just "yes."

Comment: Yes, but I preferred to write it independently from the assumption "compact resolvent", to make a precise statement. Yes, "compact resolvent" implies 0 is automatically isolated, and $\sigma(G)$ unbounded.

Comment: But I understand $0\in\rho(G_0)$ as: $G_0$ being an invertible operator; therefore: $0\notin\sigma(G_0)$ and $\sigma(G_0)$ bounded... Why we don't need the latter?

Comment: Yes, I also interpret $\rho(G_0)$ as the resolvent set (= complement of the spectrum), so $0\in\rho(G_0)$ precisely if $G_0$ is injective and $G_0^{-1}\in B(H)$ (but $G_0$ itself need not be bounded, of course).

Comment: OK, by *invertible operator* I mean  *a linear homeomorphism* $ A:H\to H$ , thus more than just $0\in\rho(A)$ . So yes, the answer was somehow misleading.